# Scrollable div with a contained list (family tree)

Tags: jquery, html, css, tree

As you can see in the snippet below, the family tree isn't showing nicely. That's because the container is not wide enough to contain it. I want to solve this by adding a scrollbar to the container but unfortunately, that doesn't work. I tried `nowrap` on the list, but to no avail. Is there any way I can do this?

jQuery is allowed as a last necessity, but IE8 has to be supported. The width of the tree is never known in advance. Therefore, a script is probably necessary that calculates the actual width of the tree.

```js
$(window).load(function(){
// Add classes for old IE
 jQuery(".tree li a:only-child, .tree li:only-child").addClass("only-child");
 jQuery(".tree li:last-child").addClass("last-child");

});
```

```css
/*Now the CSS*/
 * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.tree ul {
    padding-top: 20px;
    position: relative;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}
.tree li {
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px 5px 0 5px;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}
/*We will use ::before and ::after to draw the connectors*/
 .tree li:before, .tree li:after {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 50%;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 50%;
    height: 20px;
}
.tree li:after {
    right: auto;
    left: 50%;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}
/*We need to remove left-right connectors from elements without 
any siblings*/
 .tree li.only-child:after, .tree li.only-child:before {
    display: none;
}
/*Remove space from the top of single children*/
 .tree li.only-child {
    padding-top: 0;
}
/*Remove left connector from first child and 
right connector from last child*/
.tree li:first-child:before, .tree li.last-child:after {
    border: 0 none;
}
/*Adding back the vertical connector to the last nodes*/
 .tree li.last-child:before {
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}
.tree li:first-child:after {
    border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}
/*Time to add downward connectors from parents*/
 .tree ul ul:before {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 0;
    height: 20px;
}
.tree li a {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #666;
    font-family: arial, verdana, tahoma;
    font-size: 11px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}


/*Time for some hover effects*/

/*We will apply the hover effect the the lineage of the element also*/
 .tree li a:hover, .tree li a:hover+ul li a {
    background: #c8e4f8;
    color: #000;
    border: 1px solid #94a0b4;
}
/*Connector styles on hover*/
 .tree li a:hover+ul li::after, .tree li a:hover+ul li::before, .tree li a:hover+ul::before, .tree li a:hover+ul ul::before {
    border-color: #94a0b4;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>


<!-- Borrowed from http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/css3-family-tree -->
<div class="tree">
    <ul>
        <li class="only-child"> <a href="#">Parent</a>

            <ul>
                <li> <a href="#">Child</a>

                    <ul>
                        <li class="only-child"> <a class="only-child" href="#">Grand Child</a>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li> <a href="#">Child</a>

                    <ul>
                        <li><a class="only-child" href="#">Grand Child</a>
                        </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Grand Child</a>

                            <ul>
                                <li> <a class="only-child" href="#">Great Grand Child</a>

                                </li>
                                <li> <a class="only-child" href="#">Great Grand Child</a>

                                </li>
                                <li> <a class="only-child" href="#">Great Grand Child</a>

                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a class="only-child" href="#">Grand Child</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may use the table/table-cell display to avoid content to wrap down next line and shrink/expand as much needed.

```js
$(window).load(function(){
// Add classes for old IE
 jQuery(".tree li a:only-child, .tree li:only-child").addClass("only-child");
 jQuery(".tree li:last-child").addClass("last-child");

});
```

```css
/*Now the CSS*/
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.tree ul {
  padding-top: 20px;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
  display:table;
}
.tree li {
  display:table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px 5px 0 5px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}
/*We will use ::before and ::after to draw the connectors*/
.tree li:before, .tree li:after {
  content:'';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 50%;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 50%;
  height: 20px;
}
.tree li:after {
  right: auto;
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}
/*We need to remove left-right connectors from elements without 
any siblings*/
.tree li.only-child:after, .tree li.only-child:before {
  display: none;
}
/*Remove space from the top of single children*/
.tree li.only-child {
  padding-top: 0;
}
/*Remove left connector from first child and 
right connector from last child*/
.tree li:first-child:before, .tree li.last-child:after {
  border: 0 none;
}
/*Adding back the vertical connector to the last nodes*/
.tree li.last-child:before {
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}
.tree li:first-child:after {
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}
/*Time to add downward connectors from parents*/
.tree ul ul:before {
  content:'';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 0;
  height: 20px;
}
.tree li a {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666;
  font-family: arial, verdana, tahoma;
  font-size: 11px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}


/*Time for some hover effects*/

/*We will apply the hover effect the the lineage of the element also*/
.tree li a:hover, .tree li a:hover+ul li a {
  background: #c8e4f8;
  color: #000;
  border: 1px solid #94a0b4;
}
/*Connector styles on hover*/
.tree li a:hover+ul li::after, .tree li a:hover+ul li::before, .tree li a:hover+ul::before, .tree li a:hover+ul ul::before {
  border-color: #94a0b4;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>


<!-- Borrowed from http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/css3-family-tree -->
<div class="tree">
    <ul>
        <li class="only-child"> <a href="#">Parent</a>

            <ul>
                <li> <a href="#">Child</a>

                    <ul>
                        <li class="only-child"> <a class="only-child" href="#">Grand Child</a>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li> <a href="#">Child</a>

                    <ul>
                        <li><a class="only-child" href="#">Grand Child</a>
                        </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Grand Child</a>

                            <ul>
                                <li> <a class="only-child" href="#">Great Grand Child</a>

                                </li>
                                <li> <a class="only-child" href="#">Great Grand Child</a>

                                </li>
                                <li> <a class="only-child" href="#">Great Grand Child</a>

                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a class="only-child" href="#">Grand Child</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks very promising. One problem though: as you can see, the middle grand child has a blank space between itself and its connector. This can be solved by adding `vertical-align: top` to `.tree li`.

Comment: @BramVanroy yes of course, i only demonstrated the basic behvior of this display. min-width to 'cells' can be added too :)